# update multiple tables with regex

Tags: mysql, regex, sql-update

I need to update multilne tables with similar names but I don't know the exact names and number of tables and I need to update. I will do the same update in each table.

Example:

```
UPDATE Books, Books_2016, Books_2015, Books_2014,  ...
SET Title= "NEWTitle"
WHERE Title="Oldtitle";
```

Is it possible to use regex on name of tables?

Comment: You would almost certainly need some sort of dynamic SQL for this query.  How many possible tables do you have to search?

Comment: Right now I use it for 7 tables , but this number can br increased anytime.

Comment: It is usually a mistake to split up one table into multiple tables.  Put the tables together in a single table; this an some other problems will vanish.